# How can I remove spaces in a image tag like <image></image> in Notepad++

Tags: xml

can you please help me to replace spaces in a tag (xml file) in notepad++ ?

It's showing:

```
<image>http://www.infinitybd.com/image/cache/data/hp ScanJet 200-100x100.jpg</image>
```

Then Want to do:

```
<image>http://www.infinitybd.com/image/cache/data/hp%20ScanJet%20200-100x100.jpg</image>
```

Thanks

Comment: write %20 in place of space

Answer (score 0):

Simple press `ctrl+H` then give a space in "Find what" and "%20" in Replace with.
Click on Replace all

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, there is 4 or 5 tags like:  <item> <title></title>, <url></url>, <image></image>, <price></price> </item> then I want to replace in image tag only. for Example: <item>
    <title>HP Scaner ScanJet 200 </title>
    <url>http://www.infinitybd.com/accessories/hp-scaner-scanjet200</url>
    <image>http://www.infinitybd.com/image/cache/data/hp ScanJet 200-100x100.jpg</image>
    <price>Tk.5,500.00</price>
  </item>

Comment: May be you could try to find some way through regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you want to encode your URL, it is not about spaces. You can try with https://www.urlencoder.org/ for example.